# Alter table ошибка столбец содержит NULL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Задача - добавить поле, в существующую таблицу

```
alter table master
    add hr_id int not null;
```

Получаю ошибку

> [23502] ОШИБКА: столбец "hr_id" содержит значения NULL

Ума не приложу, в какую сторону "копать".

Comment: в такой ситуации нужно сделать 3 действия: 1) добавить колонку 2) заполнить колонку данными 3) изменить настройки колонки, добавив not null

Comment: Спасибо огромное. Я вам очень признателен

Comment: ещё можно написать `alter table master add hr_id int not null default 0`, а потом заполнить, но я не люблю этот вариант